# android studio: unique identifier for each element

Tags: android, tags, unique

I have an android application where not all elements have unique ID's. For example, two TextViews are each called "itemButton" and are on the same screen. I want to give every element a unique identifier by setting a tag on each element.

My current solution is to iterate through every element in the application and set the tag for each element. This is a very expensive solution because I have many elements. Is there another property you know of that would help identify an element other than setting a unique tag for each element?

Comment: Do you mean two `TextView`s with the same id on the same screen? Or just two with the same id in completely different parts of the app? I'm also curious what the final goal is? Maybe you're trying to do user analytics, or maybe you're just trying to assign a listener to the right view, etc.

Comment: Hi @BenP., I mean two TextViews with the same id on the same screen (I just posted an edit). This occurs throughout the app. I am trying to implement A/B testing. (I know there are other services for A/B testing, but because of some specifications, I need to take the approach I have been taking)

Comment: Can you uniquely identify them by using their parents? E.g. you have one `@+id/itemButton` inside a `FrameLayout` (with some id) and another `@+id/itemButton` inside a `LinearLayout` (with a different id). Then you could call `myFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.itemButton)` or `myLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.itemButton)` as necessary.

Comment: @BenP. yes, that works; thank you!

Comment: @BenP. I don't know if I can accept a comment as an accepted answer, but if you post your comment, I can approve it

Comment: I added an answer and elaborated on my comment a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View IDs have no special requirement that they be unique. However, you will run into difficulties if you use non-unique IDs on a single screen.

The two most common issues you will face if you use non-unique IDs are (1) failure of the system to automatically save instance state for the view and (2) `findViewById()` returning the "wrong" view.

`Activity.findViewById()` will search the view hierarchy for the first view it finds with the matching ID. If you have two views in your hierarchy with the same ID, that means you won't be able to find the second one using this method. However, you *can* use `View.findViewById()` instead.

`View.findViewById()` will search the view hierarchy *starting from the view you're invoking the method on*, which means that you can differentiate between two views with the same ID as long as they have different parents.

In your case, I suspect you can do something like the following:

```
View parentOne = findViewById(R.id.parentOne);
View childOne = parentOne.findViewById(R.id.someIdBeingReused);

View parentTwo = findViewById(R.id.parentTwo);
View childTwo = parentTwo.findViewById(R.id.someIdBeingReused);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you got it right, you should assign unique ids to your elements by using in each of them: android:id="@+id/YOUR_ID", then you can find them with findViewById(R.id.YOUR_ID), so, if you have two text views, lets say, username and password, you set the ids on each:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/username" .../>

<TextView android:id="@+id/password" .../>
```

and then you get them in your activity or fragment with:
    TextView txtUsername = findViewById(R.id.username);

```
TextView txtPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem is that my team and I have already developed the app with many elements. It is expensive to go back and change each element ID.

Comment: But how is the app working if you did it this way? how do you interact with the elements?, it sounds way to inefficient. I would say that at least the ids have to be different in the same fragment or activity, if they are the same in other activities, you should not have a problem.